# How to find JS code is working in browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, browser

I am using bootstrap modal, I dont know where I have put the js code that triggers the modal after clicking the button.

```
jQuery('#signin').modal('show');
```

I checked each file...even checked each JS file in source in browser.

How can I find which code is triggering the event in browser when I am clicking the button to open a modal?

Comment: If you are looking for the above lost in your own code somewhere, do you not have the ability to search your project via your text editor / dev environment?

Comment: I searched it, and then only i have posted this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a developer tool for a browser which will allow you to perform Javascript debugging.  Your best bet is most likely Firebug.  If you set a debug point at a line within a JS file, firebug will allow you to inspect the stack to see which line has called the function.

**Instructions**

1. In Firebug, click the script tab.
2. Select your .js file using the drop down.
3. When the JS file displays find the target line and click to the left of it, setting a debug point.
4. Load your page, the script should stop at your debug point.
5. Click the Stack tab on the right and inspect.

[image]

**Searching for Script in Firebug**

If you click the script tab you can enter a known piece of the script in the upper right hand corner of firebug, this should take you to its location in the code.

Comment: thats what I need, steps to find it

Comment: Or you can use the Inspector in Chrome, and check the Console tab for any errors.

Comment: @Terry no errors....The modal opens perfectly...I am not getting location of code

Comment: Well you'll have to do it the hard way then - take out all JS plugins but leave jQuery intact. And then progressive add the plugins back in, one at a time, and check which one triggers the modal box.

Comment: @vikasdevde Firebug also allows you to search your script.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Kevin, another option is to print the stack trace using something like:
http://www.codeovertones.com/2011/08/how-to-print-stack-trace-anywhere-in.html